# Angular 9 and GTM via angular-google-tag-manager

Tags: angular, google-tag-manager

I am using angular-google-tag-manager 1.4.2 with angular 9. I need to provide GTM in app.module.ts

```
{ provide: 'googleTagManagerId', useFactory: GoogleTagManagerFactory, deps: [apiService] }
```

and in this factory I am calling API for the GTM_ID inside the observable:

```
import { ApiService } from '../api.service';

export const GoogleTagManagerFactory = (apiService: ApiService) => {
  return apiService.getUserInfo().subscribe((apiResponse) => {
    // console.log here shows me the right GTM_ID taken from the API
    return apiResponse.googleTagManagerContainerID;
  });
};
```

but what I have in the console is

```
angular-google-tag-manager.js:62 GET https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=[object%20Object] net::ERR_ABORTED 404
```

Comment: What do you want to use GTM for? To send events to Google Analytics?

Comment: @Marek, you are sending GTM ID as an objective. Please check what you are receiving in subscribe

Comment: So I have to somehow force GoogleTagManagerFactory to send a string when it uses subscribe() to get the data from the API. How to do this here?

Comment: So I see I cannot use this for asynchronous calls. I have probably to use APP_INITIALIZER but how can I use it with this:
{ provide: 'googleTagManagerId', useFactory: GoogleTagManagerFactory, deps: [apiService] } ?